# How to know where did php extension install to in linux

Tags: php, apc, php-extension

I installed with this command

```
cd ~ 
mkdir setups
cd setups 
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.8.tgz 
tar -xvf APC-3.1.8.tgz 
cd APC-3.1.8
phpize
./configure
make
```

then where did apc.so install to ? 
Edit: Right answer is morre's

Comment: Nowhere yet I guess, not knowing the Makefile, but usually you have to "make install" to install, make without anything usually just compiles. Usually.

Comment: this is right answer . i don't make install >"<.

Answer (score 0):

could always try  "ls -R | grep apc.so" on the root.

Comment: Probably not necessary, see comment, but if searching the HD better would be "find /usr -name apc.so -type f" (skips dirs and special files, and it's most likely in /usr if it's anywhere (no "make install").